# Proxy a SOAP request from http to https

Tags: http, nginx, soap, proxy, http-proxy

I am trying to setup a proxy translating SOAP http traffic into https. The problem I'm trying to solve is a legacy desktop application and a legacy webservice which communicates via SOAP. However, the server where the web service is run does no longer allow http traffic, only https, and I do not have admin rights to allow https or setup a reverse proxy on this server.

Therefore my plan was to setup a forward proxy on a separate server for the desktop application to connect to, which then forwards the SOAP requests to the webservice using https.

Is this a sound solution? And if so, with what technology can I do this the easiest? Do I have to program it myself or is there a quick solution to this?